# Angular unit testing with Jasmine: how to remove or modify spyOn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

AngularJS v1.2.26

Jasmine v2.2.0

How can I change or remove the behavior of a `spyOn`? When I try to override it, I get the following error: `Error: getUpdate has already been spied upon`

```
var data1 = 'foo';
var data2 = 'bar';

describe("a spec with a spy", function(){

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $q;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_updateService_, _$q_){
        updateService = _updateService_;

        //spy the results of the getUpdate()
        $q = _$q_;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve( data1 );
        spyOn(updateService, 'getUpdate').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    }));

    describe('and here the spy should be different', function() {

        it('returns a different value', function() {

          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve( data2 );
          spyOn(updateService, 'getUpdate'); //ERROR HERE
          updateService.getUpdate.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

          ...

        });
    });

...
```

When I remove the second spyOn the test doesn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine SpyOn same method more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200532/jasmine-spyon-same-method-more-than-once)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can just overwrite it

```
updateService.getUpdate = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(etc)
```

Comment: Is there way to remove the spy entirely? To go back to the original function?

Comment: The big question is, if you don't the same functionality in every test, why have a global spy at all? If you want to set the spy for every test, then set the spy for every test.

Comment: @Jan If I have fifty tests, and only one of them has a spy for a function that is different from the rest, I'd rather just change it the one time there instead of every single test.

Comment: well, in my case it's on a global object (defined by native code). So I have multiple specs that need to return different values in different situations....

Comment: would it return to its original implementation by calling jasmine.createSpy().and.callThrought()?

Answer (score 36):

You can override the return value of the spy

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve( data1 );

    var getUpdateSpy = spyOn(updateService, 'getUpdate').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);



    var newDeferred = $q.defer();
    newDeferred.resolve( data2 );

    getUpdateSpy.and.returnValue(newDeferred.promise);
```

Comment: Works on 18/6/2019

Comment: That may work if all your code is in the same describe, but otherwise not because getUpdateSpy is not defined...

Comment: @GarfieldKlon You can work around that by defining the variable `getUpdateSpy` in the parent `describe` block.

Answer (score 35):

Since jasmine v2.5, use the global `allowRespy()` setting.

```js
jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);
```

You'll be able to call `spyOn()` multiple times, when you don't want and/or have access to the first spy. Beware it will return the previous spy, if any is already active.

```js
spyOn(updateService, 'getUpdate').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
...
spyOn(updateService, 'getUpdate').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
```

Comment: Honestly, this is the answer I've been looking for ages. I wish it was more prevalent on the internet. A million thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

**More easier and simpler way:**

```
updateService.getUpdate.and.returnValue(Observable.of({status:true}));
```

It will return the value.

Comment: Thank you. Everyone else is missing the obvious answer.

Comment: It seems that your type system is not complaining. That begs the question: why use **Type**script at all?

Answer (score 10):

Another option:

```
(yourService.method as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

the green check-marked answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
yourCoolService.createThing = jasmine.createSpy('notreal', function(){}).and.returnValue();
```

your jasmine test will run but when you go to fire up your app typescript will yell loudly at you if you don't put a random string and an empty function as the args to `createSpy()`.

Comment: This is probably due to an updated version of Jasmine. I am using 2.7 and this works for me.