# Jasmine SpyOn same method more than once

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an angular controller with a method that calls `$location.search()` twice.

First time is just `$location.search()` to return the value.
Second time is `$location.search("foo", null)` to clear it.

I have the following spy in my unit test:
`spyOn($location, "search").and.returnValue({ foo: "bar" });`

It appears the spy returns `{foo:"bar"}` even when my implementation does `$location.search("foo", null)`.

I need a way to have two different spies for the same method depending on the arguments.

I need this expect:
`expect($location.search().foo).toEqual(null);`
to pass at the end of the unit test.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can go about it different ways. If you have time to change the spy implementation during your testcase, you can do this:

```
var searchSpy = spyOn($location,'search');

searchSpy.and.returnValue(null);
// do stuff
searchSpy.and.returnValue({ foo: "bar" });
// do other stuff
```

If the calls are triggered by a method in your code, and you cannot change the spy implementation in between, then you can create a function that takes the arguments and responds appropriately:

```
spyOn($location,'search').and.callFake(function(someParam){
  if (someParam) { 
      return { foo: "bar" };
  } else {
      return { foo: null };
  }
});
```

Of course you can go crazy with logic in your callFake implementation, but beware, I think in that case it might be a code smell. Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: At least with `spyOnProperty` it doesn't seem to be possible to use `returnValue` multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

Also it's possible to call spy properties on the mocked object directly. The code may look like:

```
spyOn($location,'search');

$location.search.and.returnValue(null);
// do stuff
$location.search.and.returnValue({ foo: "bar" })
// do other stuff
```

In case of typescript it may look like:

```
spyOn($location,'search');

(<jasmine.Spy>$location.search).and.returnValue(null);
// do stuff
(<jasmine.Spy>$location.search).and.returnValue({ foo: "bar" })
// do other stuff
```

Posting this answer because it may look a bit cleaner and doesn't require additional variables.